# Template template partial specialization failure: "expected a class template"

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

This example code generates `expected a class template, got std::pair <_T1, _T2>`. I tried using `struct Struct <std::pair> {};`, but then parameters `T` and `M` become undeducible. How to avoid this?

```
    template <template <class...> class>
    struct Struct {};

    template <class T, class M>
    struct Struct <std::pair <T, M>> {};
```

Comment: `std::pair` is class template, `std::pair <_T1, _T2>` is not. You might change the primary template declaration to `template <class> struct Struct {};`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending of what you want

```
template <template <class...> class>
struct Struct {};

template <>
struct Struct <std::pair>
{
    // Specialization
};
```

or

```
template <typename> struct Struct {};

template <typename First, typename Second>
struct Struct <std::pair<First, Second>>
{
    // Specialization
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a valid specialization for your template.

The reason why is because `std::pair<T, M>` is a full specialization of the class template `std::pair` and therefore a class. Your template expects a class template parameter which is exactly what the compiler is telling you.